# Virtualization solution

Tags: virtualization, vmware, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am looking into playing around with virtualization and I was wondering if there is any software that acts as the host OS but operates much like virtual box or parallels?  What I mean by this is basically is there an "OS" that more or less acts as a window manager for other virtualized desktops?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Citrix XenClient](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=2300325) does exactly what you're looking for (and they've got a free version, XenClient Express)

Unfortunately due to the nature of virtualization on "bare metal" (without an OS) the [Hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) (the OS bit that hosts the VMs) needs to be compatible with your exact hardware.

For more information, checkout the [XenClient Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/subfeature.asp?contentID=2300408). The best value machine you can get is probably the Dell Optiplex 780.